# How to preview output from react-thermal-printer

Tags: node.js

The library "react-thermal-printer" allow to print bills & below is output buffer which is given on port to print :-

```
import { render, Printer, Text } from 'react-thermal-printer';
import { connect } from 'node:net';

const data = await render(
  <Printer type="epson">
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
  </Printer>
);

const conn = connect({
  host: '192.168.0.99',
  port: 9100,
  timeout: 3000,
}, () => {
  conn.write(Buffer.from(data), () => {
    conn.destroy();
  });
});
```

Ask is to view the preview of receipt before it prints.

Below is snippet to convert buffer to base 64 but seems base64 generate is corrupted.

```
const generateImageFromBuffer = buffer => {
    let _buffer = new Buffer.from(buffer, 'base64');
    return _buffer.toString('base64');
  };
```

Any clue how to view preview of "react-thermal-printer"